# Numerical Range of A and A transpose.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I was playing around with the numerical range [NR] (or field of value) of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ lately.

And was actually looking for a proof to show:
\begin{equation} A=A^H : F(A) = F(A^H) \Longrightarrow F(A) = [a,b] \in \mathbb{R} \end{equation}
What is proven below [1].

But I asked myself, what happens if you transpose an arbitrary matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$?

$$F(A)\stackrel{?}{=}\beta F(A^T)$$

---

**Update:**

There was a little mistake in a book, that switched up $\gamma$ and $\beta$, leading to this question.

To clarify $F(A)=F(A^T)=F(PBP)$ with $P,B$ as stated in the question.

---

Since you can use unitary matrices without changing the NR:

$$F(A)=F(U^HBU)=F(B)$$

You can bring $A$ in **lower** triangular form $B$ and compare $F(B^T)$ with $F(P^HBP)$ where

$$P^H=P = \begin{bmatrix}&&1\\
&...& \\ %\udots \iddots not working
1 & &\end{bmatrix}$$

But I am kinda stuck here ...

*It felt like it's just a $90°$ turn for a $2\times2$ matrix, but I can't prove it for $2 \times 2$ nor scale the idea...*

**To sum up the question.**

Is there a (linear) map $g$ with $g(F(A)) = F(A^T)$ and if it exists, is it a rotation?

---

[1]
\begin{equation}A = A^H \Rightarrow \exists \ U \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n},\ \exists \ D=diag(\lambda_{11},\dots,\lambda_{nn})\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} :UU^H= I,\ A=U^HDU\\\begin{split}
F(A^H)=F(A) &= F(U^HDU) \\ & = F(D) \\ & = [min(\lambda_{11},\dots,\lambda_{nn}),\ max(\lambda_{11},\dots,\lambda_{nn})]\\ &=[\alpha ,\beta] \in \mathbb{R}\end{split}\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for an $\alpha \in F(A)$, we have (for some $x$ and $y$)
$$
\bar a = \overline{x^H (Ay)} = (Ay)^Hx = y^HA^H x
$$
So in general, we have $F(A^H) = \overline{F(A)}$.

Comment: Let A be real lower triangle.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 \\
\beta & \gamma \end{bmatrix}$$
And P be as above.

You would get $F(A^H)=F(A^T)$ but $F(A)=F(P^HRP)$
First would imply an ellipsis with a foci in $\alpha , \beta$ with a height of $|\gamma |$, the second would imply an ellipsis with foci $\gamma , \beta$ and a height of $|\alpha |$.
At least from my view.

Comment: PS.:

Let $||x||= 1 $and
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Your formal would imply $$\overline{x^H(Ax)}=x^HA^Hx$$
$$\overline{x^H} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\overline{x}=x^H \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}x$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.
$$
\bar x^H\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1} \bar x = |x_1|^2 + x_1\bar x_2 = 
x^H \pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}x
$$

Comment: And indeed, for any permutation matrix $P$ and any matrix $R$, we have $F(P^HRP) = F(R)$.

Comment: Also, it's an **ellipse**, not an ellipsis.

Comment: It's an elliptical disk, but you are right about the $\overline{x^HAx}$. Thus $F(A) = F(A^T)$?

PS.: It's $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+x_1 \overline{x_2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40073/discussion-between-patrick-abraham-and-omnomnomnom).